# How to convert timezone offset text "+01:00" to timespan

Tags: c#, timezone, timespan

I have an API which will accept timezone offset as string. I need to convert the timezone to TimeSpan and add the timespan with the data i have which is in UTC. Here is what i'm trying.

```
private bool TryGetHrAndMinFromTimeZone(string timeZone, out TimeSpan result)
    {
        try
        {
            var isPositive = !timeZone.StartsWith("-");
            var hrAndMin = string.Concat(timeZone.Where(x => x != '-' && x != '+')).Split(':');
            var hr = int.Parse(hrAndMin[0]);
            var min = int.Parse(hrAndMin[1]);
            result = isPositive ? new TimeSpan(hr, min, 0) : new TimeSpan(-hr, -min, 0);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Provided TimeZone '{0}' is Invalid ", timeZone));
        }
    }
```

Is there any better option to do it?

Comment: Hey, try this   --> TimeSpan.TryParse("-07:00", out TimeSpan ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try

```
TimeSpan.TryParse("-07:00", out TimeSpan ts) //for -07:00
TimeSpan.TryParse("07:00", out TimeSpan ts) //for +07:00
```

for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones#converting-datetimeoffset-values

Comment: Thanks for the input. It works nicely with -ve timezone offsets. But not with +ve timezone offsets. can you provide an input on that?

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha remove plus(+) sign from the string.

Answer (score 3):

The `DateTimeOffset` type can parse offsets of this format using the `zzz` specifier.  Thus you can write a function such as the following:

```
static TimeSpan ParseOffset(string s)
{
    return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, "zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Offset;
}
```

Another approach, you can parse with `TimeSpan.ParseExact` if you strip off the sign first and handle it yourself:

```
static TimeSpan ParseOffset(string s)
{
    var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(s.Substring(1), @"hh\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return s[0] == '-' ? ts.Negate() : ts;
}
```

Or, as Manish showed in his answer, you can let `TimeSpan.Parse` attempt to figure out the string.  It works if you remove the `+` sign first.

```
static TimeSpan ParseOffset(string s)
{
    return TimeSpan.Parse(s.Replace("+", ""), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```